# Call to a member function get() on a non-object in Controller Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, orocrm

I'm new in OroCRM and Symfony2,in method update of my DefaultController I create an instance of OroCRM\Bundle\MagentoBundle\Controller\CustomerController and call its method

```
    $customerController = new CustomerController();
    $customerController->update($extendCustomer);
```

$extendCustomer is an inheritace of OroCRM\Bundle\MagentoBundle\Entity\Customer

```
    class ExtendCustomer extends Customer
```

But when I call method update of CustomerController it throws this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /var/www/html/crm-application/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php on line 350
```

I have worked on it for 2 days with everything i can search on google, but it still doesn't work. I understand that there are something with services, which i don't understand much.
Please give me some advices. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post your CustomerController code?

Comment: Never use OroCRM, but you cannot use Symfony2 Controller like that. Controller is created by Service container with some injection stuffs. So I think error 'Call to a member function get() on a non-object' caused by controller is calling method 'get' from $container variable which is not created.

Instead of creating controller like that, you should create a service which has update method and handle your logic code inside.

Take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html
and http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html

Comment: Thanks for your help my friends. I know that using service is common way in symfony2 but i still don't understand it well. So I add this line of code to my controller to inject a container, it works. :) $customerController->setContainer($this->container);

Comment: Thanks for your help again, i'm trying to find out something about service in Symfony and OroCRM

Comment: The controller can't be instantiated by you, the controller must be instantiated by symfony that is the purpose of a framework : to have a concrete implementation of the IOC Designe Pattern